# Error al tratar de recuperar clave con encode PHP

Tags: php, mysql, php7, base64

En un intento de recuperar contraseña olvidada con ayuda de un correo electrónico en PHP y MYSQL, envío el mensaje con la nueva clave y trato de mandarla al correo ingresado **en claro** pero no lo hace. Si realiza la actualización en la tabla con la nueva contraseña pero no la manda en claro a la cuenta de correo electrónico.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])){

    $mail = $_POST['email'];

    function generaPassword(){  
        $cadena = "123AN*xk78acc994";
        $longitudCadena=strlen($cadena);    
        $pass = "";
        $longitudPass=8;    
        for($i=1 ; $i<=$longitudPass ; $i++){
            $pos=rand(0,$longitudCadena-1);     
            $pass .= substr($cadena,$pos,1);
        }
        return $pass;
    }
    $clave = generaPassword();
    $claveEncriptada =base64_encode($clave);

            //Conexion con la base
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mydbname");

    $sql = $conn->query("Update empresasregistradas Set password='$claveEncriptada' Where email='$mail'");


    require_once("PHPMailer-5.2.11/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

        //Nuevo correo electronico.
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

    $mail->Username = "myemail@mail.com";
    $mail->Password = "mypsw";
    $mail->setFrom('myemail@mail.com', 'recuperar PSW');
        //Titulo email.
    $mail->Subject = "Nueva Contraseña";
        //Cuerpo email con HTML.
        $mail->Body = "Tu contraseña actualizada es: ". base64_decode($clave); 

        //Comprobamos el envio.
        if(!$mail->send()) {                    
            echo'<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Ocurrió un error inesperado con él envió del correo electrónico, inténtelo de nuevo más tarde, disculpa las molestias.");
            window.location.href="recupera.php";
            </script>'; 
        } else {
            $error = "Se envio correctamente el correo electrónico.";
            echo'<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Se ha enviado el correo electrónico con su nueva contraseña.");
            window.location.href="recupera.php";
            </script>';

        } 
    }     else ;
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
        <title>Recuperar Contraseña</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="noprint">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-warning">
                <img src="img/logoOscar.png" style="width: 9%">
                <div class="container">

                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="login.php"> SISTEMA 
                    </a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </nav><br>

            <center><h1>Recuperar Contraseña</h1></center><br>

            <form action="recuperar.php" method="POST">
                <div class="container">
                    <h5 for="recuperar">Correo Electrónico:</h5>
                    <input class="form-group col-md-6" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email">&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Enviar">Recuperar</button>
                    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Ingresa tu email de registro al sistema y recibirás un correo electrónico con tu contraseña nueva.</small><br><br><br>
                    <a href="" onclick="history.back(); return false" class='btn btn-info'>Regresar</a>
                </div>
            </form>



            <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Fijate en la pagina de PHPMailer tiene una opción de activar debug y enviar lo que hace paso a paso al log de php. Con eso podes ver donde está el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Antes de la explicación es sumamente importante recalcar que *NUNCA* se debe poder hacer una transformación de una contraseña encriptada a su versión desencriptada sin que una persona provea la clave de desencriptación (más detalle en https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6068/is-it-possible-to-securely-store-passwords-using-reversible-encryption).

El problema está en que quieres hacer `base_decode` de la variable `$clave` que nunca fue codificada en base 64. Deberías hacer `base_decode` de `$claveEncriptada`